# Backbone model.save calls error function on status code 200

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, express

```
this.model.save(newModel, {error: function (e){
        alert("Error trying to save contact: " + e);
        console.log(e);
    }});
```

Above is the code that is running on the client side. the server code is

```
model.update_contact(contact, function(err){
        if(err){
            res.statusCode = 500;
            return res.json({"Database error" : err});
        }
        return res.end();
    });
```

inspecting the network traffic i see that the server responds with status code 200 but the web page shows the alert message "Error trying to save contact: [Object object]"

p.s the db query is successful

Answer (score 2):

Backbone expects to get the model's JSON back in response to PUT or POST requests IIRC.

Instead of returning `res.end()` try this:

```
return res.json(contact);
```

Answer (score 0):

Dumb mistake, my server was not properly returning the object back. Once i added code to return the object everything ran fine.

Comment: Unrelated, but if you are returning `res.end()` for whatever reason you should be setting `res.statusCode = 204` before hand. See here: http://httpstatus.es/204